# C# equivalent of Java's mkdirs()

Tags: c#, java, mkdirs

I am trying to convert a Java program to c#.

Is there a equivalent to Java's mkdirs() command which recursively makes folders?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simply:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToDir)
```

This will create any and all directories specified in the given path.  (Just like `mkdirs`)

See the documentation here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

> Any and all directories specified in
>   path are created, unless they already
>   exist or unless some part of path is
>   invalid

Comment: @jjnguy you'd typed more. I added the quote later.

Comment: I had typed up `Directory.Create()` and almost submitted that as an answer.  But I decided to go and check the docs.  That's where I lost most of my time. :)